# xpath reference in Odoo 15 and 16, how to resolve it

Tags: xpath, odoo, qweb, odoo-16

**ver.15 template**:

```
<a role="button" t-if="website_sale_order and website_sale_order.website_order_line" class="btn btn-primary float-right d-none d-xl-inline-block" href="/shop/checkout?express=1">
  <span class="">Process Checkout</span>
  <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" />
</a>
```

**ver.15 xpath expression to above template which works fine**:

```
<template id="zhen_product_cart_line_validate_button" inherit_id="website_sale.cart">
    <xpath expr="//a[@href='/shop/checkout?express=1']" position="attributes">
         <attribute name="t-att-style">'' if website.zhen_products_validation() else 'display:none;'</attribute>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

this will open a Modal page.

==========================================

there are changes in ver.16 on Odoo provided modules.

**ver.16 template**:

```
<t t-set="redirect_url" t-value="'/web/login?redirect=/shop/checkout' if redirect_to_sign_in else '/shop/checkout?express=1'"/>
```

**ver.16 xpath expression**:

how i can use xpath for this in ver.16? *i tried below* but it is showing error while Upgrading module through UI (Apps).

```
<xpath expr="//t[@t-value='/shop/checkout?express=1']" position="attributes">
```

**Error**:

```
Element '<xpath expr="//t[@t-value=&#39;/shop/checkout?express=1&#39;]">' cannot be located in parent view
```

kindly guide to resolve this.
regards

Comment: `@t-value='x'` means the value of `t-value` EQUALS `x`. The value in the odoo 16 template is a lot longer than your value in the xpath expression...

Comment: thank you @CZoellner, i knew it and that's why i am asking experts for help that how i can reference it. is there any way? how to because i didn't yet used it and don't know how to do it.

Comment: You could either use the whole value of `t-value` or post more of the template, because without more XML it's difficult to find more ways for XPath.

Comment: i can send in a text file in Answer if there is option to attach because of restriction of number of characters here...

Comment: template file path on my machine is: addons/website_sale/views/template.xml  in this file the template is:  <template id="cart" name="Shopping Cart">

Comment: okay i see that template probably is a bit big for the question, And i can see that it can suck to use XPath for it. I would try to be pragmatic and just `<xpath expr="//t[@t-set='redirect_url'" position="after">` and just set the variable again with my desired value.

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic way to set the `redirect_url` variable to the desired one would be by setting it again right after the first creation of it:

```xml
<xpath expr="//t[@t-set='redirect_url']" position="after">
    <t t-set="redirect_url" t-value="my desired url in python expression"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: thanks, will check it and confirm. hope this solve the problem. kind regards

Comment: hi @CZoellner, thank you for your passion to help us. i tried your code and now the error during Upgrade has gone but don't know why the modal page is not opened. will check further. one more code is fine and not showing error but also can't open modal page.   ( it uses:  expr="//t[contains )
<xpath expr="//t[contains(@t-value, '/shop/checkout?express=1')]" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="t-att-style">'' if website.zhen_products_validation() else 'display:none;'</attribute>
</xpath>